# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in non async function in Node / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having some issues understanding this error. I have a function called getDeliveryDate() that is called from an endpoint. This function seems non async function, but I am getting an unhandled promise error:

```
// Deadlines increments are in minutes
function getDeliveryDate(
  inputDate,
  normalDeadline,
  fastDeadline,
  fastDelivery
) {
  var deliveryDate = new Date();

  try {
    !fastDelivery
      ? deliveryDate.setTime(inputDate + normalDeadline * 60 * 1000)
      : deliveryDate.setTime(inputDate + fastDeadline * 60 * 1000);

    return deliveryDate;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("getDeliveryDate error:".error, error);//  <-- this line is okey, I am using colors library
  }
```

And this is where is call getDeliveryDate

```
...
     try {
              blockFields.finishDate = getDeliveryDate( // <-- the call
                Date.now(),
                req.body.blockOptions.deadline,
                req.body.blockOptions.fastDeadline,
                req.body.blockOptions.fastDelivery
              );
            } catch (error) {
              console.log("getDeliveryDate error".error, error); // <-- this line is okey, I am using colors library
            }
...
```

What I am missing? Is getDeliveryDate an async function? How can I properly handle its errors?

**UPDATE**

I was using a variable that I later modified, so no longer existed. After correcting the error, I am still unsure about how to catch an error for this function.

Now everything is working, but if I enter a wrong variable I am still not catching the error and getting this error (i.e. if I enter a wrong finishDate value):

(node:50620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: blocks validation failed: finishDate: Cast to Date failed for value "Invalid Date" at path "finishDate"

Why my catch(error) is not working?

Comment: Is your endpoint route declared  as async? The code seems correct, though I am a little dubious about that !fastDelivery line. But if the endpoint itself is async, an error in the values sent to the function would probably cause a promise rejection.

Comment: @jmrueda, Out of curiosity, what is `"getDeliveryDate error".error`?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention. console.log("getDeliveryDate error".error, error) is fine, I am using the library colors to log in different colors.

Comment: The endpoint is not async @tutiplain

Answer (score 1):

Add `--trace-warnings` to your arguments for launching Node.  It should show you a stack trace of the unhandled errors.

However, it does look like this line `console.log("getDeliveryDate error".error, error);` may be the culprit.  You have an error in the catch block but there is nothing to catch *that* error.